# New command for multiple subsection

Tags: spacing, macros, table-of-contents, sectioning

I am writing an university report and I have to answer to a series of topics divided in points.
I'd like to obtain a header like this 1.1.a,b,c.
I have written this command to generate a single subsubsection referring to multiple points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcount\tmp

\newcommand{\multisub}[2][1]{%
\vspace{1.2\baselineskip plus .35\baselineskip minus.07\baselineskip}%
%\vspace{.5em}%
{\bf\thesubsection.%
\tmp=0%
\advance\tmp by 2%
%#1 max num
%#2 text
\loop%
    \advance\tmp by 1%
    \addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}%
    \alph{subsubsection},%
    \ifnum \tmp<#1%
\repeat%
\addtocounter{subsubsection}{1}%
\alph{subsubsection} #2\\%
}%
%    \vspace{.5em}%
\vspace{.8\baselineskip plus .07\baselineskip}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}%

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\lipsum[1]
\multisub[2]{First two points}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see it has the form I'm looking for, but the spacing after the subsubsection header is wrong, as if the space after the header comes only after the first line of text.

How can I solve it? And how can I add this new subsection to the table of contents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can define a `\multisubsection` command for coping with more subsections at a time.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book} % oneside just to make a sensible picture
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\normalthesubsection}{%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}%
}
\normalthesubsection

% add space for the composite numbers, adapt to your need
% increasing or decreasing 5em
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline {2}{3.8em}{5em}}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multisubsection}{mO{#3}m}
 {% #1 = number of subsections to span
  % #2 = optional short title
  % #3 = title
  \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 - 1 }
   {
    \stepcounter{subsection}
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \alph{subsection}, }
   }
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\l_tmpa_tl\alph{subsection}}
  \subsection[#2]{#3}
  \normalthesubsection
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

\subsection{First point}

\kant[1]

\multisubsection{3}{Three more points}\label{a}

\ref{a}\kant[2]

\subsection{Another point}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also `\multisubsection{<n>}[Title for the toc]{Title in the document}` is supported.

How does this work? When a `\multisubsection` is called, I step the relevant counter one time less than the argument specifies, collecting the “numbers” (in this case, letters) followed by a comma in `\l_tmpa_tl`; then I redefine `\thesubsection` to be as usual, but with the insertion of `\l_tmpa_tl` before the final number; the `\subsection` command called in the background will do the final stepping and print the full number. Finally, the standard meaning of `\thesubsection` is restored.

Comment: thanks a lot! exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @LucaC. You're welcome. I changed a little the code. A `\label` command can now be used as usual. Note that you can even call `\multisubsection{1}{Title}`, so if you later change your mind about some points, you just need to change the number.

Comment: amazing, I've added your code to my report and works perfectly. May I ask you, why have you called the new command right after its definition?

Comment: @LucaC. That's the initialization for `\thesubsection` in the required form “Chapter number.Section number.Subsection letter”. Just avoiding code duplication.